# Multiple Bootstrap carousel conflict

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a homepage that is using part of the core Bootstrap carousel components for two different carousels.

The problem is, sometimes when you reload the page or clear the cache, the slider at the top doesn't always seem to load. Trying to figure out why this is. Wanted to see if someone could take a look at this page.

https://www.cento.com/index-test.php

Comment: If you remove some other elements from the page does the problem still occur? How small can you make the page, and still see the problem?

If you could do that, and then share your code example here, I think it'll be easier for people to work with and isolate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By review your site i think you forgot to active first slide of your slider with `id="bs-carousel"` apply `class="item slides active"`  to first item of your slider